# Connection to table denied in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2012

I am trying to manipulate a table in SQL Server with node. I've succeeded to connect to the database but when I do a query request I get this error :

> SELECT permission was denied on the object `Customer`

I've tried this command but it didn't work :

```
USE NodeDB;

GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::Customer TO test;
GO
```

This is the code I've written in node :

```
/*--------------------Connection--------------------------------*/
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'test',
    password: '11111',
    server: 'ICEFOX-PC\\SQLSQL',
    database: 'NodeDB'
    }

sql.connect(config, function(err) {

if (err){
    throw err ;
} else{
    console.log('connected');
}

/*--------------------Connection--------------------------------*/
var request = new sql.Request([config]);

request.query('select * from Customer', function(err, recordset) {
  if (err) {
    throw err ;
  } else {
    console.dir(recordset);
  });
```

Comment: What part of the error message isn't making sense? The user you are connecting with does not have permission to select from the Customer table.

Comment: Sounds like you need to grant select permission to the user on 'customer' table .

Comment: so how to grant permission to the user ? because i've executed this command USE NodeDB; GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::Customer TO test; GO 
and i still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried/verified to connect/select by using SQL Server Management Studio with test user logged in?

Comment: it worked with SQL Server Management Studio maybe the error is in the node.js code

Comment: Try to connect with sa user from node.js and monitor messages with SQL Server Profiler. Then do the same with test user.

Comment: yes it worked 
go lo login properties of the specified user and in securables part give the grants you want to the user